# No online survival mode games for MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When I try and `Find Match` on Modern Warfare 3 Survival Mode, it keeps searching but never finds anyone.

Has anyone else experienced this? Why is this?

Comment: Get a PS3, that should fix it! My guess is that is simply nobody else to match you too. I also found when I played spec ops online it was overly laggy, I wonder if this is due to the small pool of players in which there are in spec ops and therefore the quality of the connection is not a priority like it is in multiplayer online

Comment: @musefan Yeah perhaps just not enough people are playing spec ops! Shame really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [patch](http://www.mw3forum.com/showthread.php?t=49842) put out on the 24th that supposedly fixed some spec ops matchmaking issues.  A matchmaking bug might have been the source of your issues.